# Parsing nested JSON from API in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm working on JSON data from this API call:
https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?year=2022&branch=01&productCode=01.0010.094.01&page=1&limit=10&format=json&api-version=1.2

This is page 1, but there are 49 pages in total, therefore a part of my code deals (successfully) with pagination. I don't want to save this JSON in a file and, if I can avoid it, don't really want to import the 'json' package - but will do if necessary.

A variation of this code works correctly if I'm pulling entire ['data']['agreements'] dictionary (or is it a list...).
But I don't want that, I want individual parameters for all the 'attributes' of each 'agreement'. In my code below I'm trying to pull the 'provider-name' attribute, and would like to get a list of all the provider names, without any other data there.

But I keep getting the "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error in line 18. I've tried many ways to get this data which is nested within a list nested within a dictionary, etc. like splitting it further into another 'for' loop, but no success.

```
import requests
import math
import pandas as pd


baseurl = 'https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?year=2022&branch=01&productCode=01.0010.094.01&page=1&limit=10&format=json&api-version=1.2'

def main_request(baseurl, x):
    r = requests.get(baseurl + f'&page={x}')
    return r.json()

def get_pages(response):
    return math.ceil(response['meta']['count'] / 10)

def get_names(response):
    providerlist = []
    all_data = response['data']['agreements']
    for attributes1 in all_data ['data']['agreements']:
        item = attributes1['attributes']['provider-name']
        providers = {
            'page1': item,
        }

    providerlist.append(providers)
    return providerlist

mainlist = []
data = main_request(baseurl, 1)
for x in range(1,get_pages(data)+1):
    mainlist.extend(get_names(main_request(baseurl, x)))

mydataframe = pd.DataFrame(mainlist)

print(mydataframe)
```

Comment: The simple solution is that you need to use integers to index lists. If you use something else than an integer and you expected to index something else than a list, you need to figure out why that something is a list and not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from the Json to the dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = "https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements?year=2022&branch=01&productCode=01.0010.094.01&page={}&limit=10&format=json&api-version=1.2"

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 5): # <-- increase page numbers here
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(page)).json()

    for a in data["data"]["agreements"]:
        all_data.append({"id": a["id"], **a["attributes"], "link": a["links"]['related']})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| id | code | technical-code | origin-code | service-type | service-name | amount | updated-at | provider-code | provider-nip | provider-regon | provider-registry-number | provider-name | provider-place | year | branch | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75f1b5a0-34d1-d827-8970-89b6b593be86 | 0113/3202010/01/2022/01 | 0113/3202010/01/2022/01 | 0113/3202010/01/2022/01 | 01 | Podstawowa Opieka Zdrowotna | 14583.7 | 2022-07-11T20:04:39 | 3202010 | 8851039259 | 89019398100026 | 000000001951-W-02 | NZOZ PRAKTYKA LEKARZA RODZINNEGO JAN WOLAŃCZYK | JEDLINA-ZDRÓJ | 2022 | 01 | https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/75f1b5a0-34d1-d827-8970-89b6b593be86?format=json&api-version=1.2 |
| 1840cf6e-10ba-33a1-81f1-9f58c613d705 | 0113/3302665/01/2022/01 | 0113/3302665/01/2022/01 | 0113/3302665/01/2022/01 | 01 | Podstawowa Opieka Zdrowotna | 1479 | 2022-08-03T20:00:22 | 3302665 | 9281731555 | 390737391 | 000000023969-W-02 | NZOZ "MEDICA" | PĘCŁAW | 2022 | 01 | https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/1840cf6e-10ba-33a1-81f1-9f58c613d705?format=json&api-version=1.2 |
| 954eb365-e232-fd29-10f7-c8af21c07470 | 0113/3402005/01/2022/01 | 0113/3402005/01/2022/01 | 0113/3402005/01/2022/01 | 01 | Podstawowa Opieka Zdrowotna | 1936 | 2022-09-02T20:01:17 | 3402005 | 6121368883 | 23106871400021 | 000000002014-W-02 | PRZYCHODNIA OGÓLNA TSARAKHOV OLEG | BOLESŁAWIEC | 2022 | 01 | https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/954eb365-e232-fd29-10f7-c8af21c07470?format=json&api-version=1.2 |
| 7dd72607-ab9f-7217-87b9-8e4ed2bc5537 | 0113/3202025/01/2022/01 | 0113/3202025/01/2022/01 | 0113/3202025/01/2022/01 | 01 | Podstawowa Opieka Zdrowotna | 0 | 2022-04-14T20:01:42 | 3202025 | 8851557014 | 891487450 | 000000002063-W-02 | "PRZYCHODNIA LEKARSKA ZDROWIE BIELAK, PIEC I SZYMANIAK SPÓŁKA PARTNERSKA" | NOWA RUDA | 2022 | 01 | https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/7dd72607-ab9f-7217-87b9-8e4ed2bc5537?format=json&api-version=1.2 |
| bb60b21d-38da-1f2e-a7fd-5a45453e7370 | 0113/3102115/01/2022/01 | 0113/3102115/01/2022/01 | 0113/3102115/01/2022/01 | 01 | Podstawowa Opieka Zdrowotna | 414 | 2022-10-18T20:01:17 | 3102115 | 8941504470 | 93009444900038 | 000000001154-W-02 | PRAKTYKA LEKARZA RODZINNEGO WALDEMAR CHRYSTOWSKI | WROCŁAW | 2022 | 01 | https://api.nfz.gov.pl/app-umw-api/agreements/bb60b21d-38da-1f2e-a7fd-5a45453e7370?format=json&api-version=1.2 |

Comment: Andrej, thank you very much for your help. That's a neat code. I'll learn from this. But I'm still stuck on part of my initial question - what if I don't want all the 'attributes' but only a couple of them, e.g. only 'amount' and 'provider-code'? I'm trying things like all_data.append({**a["attributes"]['amount']}) and that's not working...

Comment: @MichaelWiz Then construct the dataframe as I shown in the question. Then you can filter the dataframe for the columns you want. For example `df = df[['id', 'code']]` will give you dataframe with only two columns.

Comment: Great stuff. Haven't thought of that. Works beautifully. Thank you!